What's the best way to ask a similar question, but targeting a new OS?
I'm interested in asking a question specifically targeting Windows 11.  I was able to find a Super User question focusing on basically the same topic from over a decade ago, before Windows 11 existed.
What's the best way to get answers for an operating system that didn't exist when the question was asked?

If you ask the same question, and the answer to the existing question applies to your question, it will be just closed as a duplicate. The answer to the question you linked to still applies to Windows 11

@Ramhound For the specific example, the answer could possibly be your comment above (assuming it's correct... that's the challenge with answers as comments: they aren't subject to the normal voting process, so there's no established feedback system to indicate the community's perception of their accuracy). Technology & features change when new products are released, so often answers change too. Having people guess "well, maybe nothing has changed" when a major new OS version has been released isn't a good option. The community member/visitor won't have confidence they have a relevant answer.

I am not going to submit an answer saying you shouldn’t ask a question you don’t know the answer to because it might be a duplicate. Furthermore, an answer saying “nothing as changed”, isn’t an acceptable answer here at Super User. The only correct action (IMO) would be a close vote as a duplicate or an answer to the question that is more than “nothing as changed”. Good thing it takes more than 1 person to close a question normally or even in the case of a good badge a single user with numerous answers to questions linked to that particular tag.

First, you have to review the previous question and the answers given on it. If those answers are still relevant to the OS you're interested in, then you should not post a question. If you are able to, add a comment to the other question or answers noting they still apply on the newer OS.
If the solutions on that previous question do NOT solve the problem you're having, you need to determine whether this is due to the OS difference, or some other issue. As you write out a new question, recognize the previous, and clearly note your efforts to solve your problem using the solutions proposed there, and how those failed to do so.
Frankly, this isn't specific to OS-difference issues, this is just the steps anyone should follow on this site any time they find a question that is similar to their own but for which the existing answers do not solve the problem. Use the information in those existing Q/A sets to guide your own troubleshooting and self-resolution efforts, and record all that as you write your own question. This helps on several levels: It results in a better question by clearly demonstrating self effort and recording research done, and it makes it more clear the previous solutions don't work to a duplicate flag is less likely to happen.

Post a question tailored for the new operating system, but make sure you specifically tag it appropriately for the new OS.  This way, it will be clear that you want answers relevant to the specific target OS.

Create a bounty for the existing question.  You can create a bounty for the old question to draw attention to it and hopefully generate some relevant answers.
